# How can i change listview from another fragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

I have in my application 2 tabs. one is contacts and the second is favorites.

I use 2 fragments and 2 list view for each tab.

In my list view there is the name and a star i want to add the option

that user can click the star in the contacts fragment and its add the user to the favorites list view fragments.

I'm using custom adapter. and i have no idea how can i do that.

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> {

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.contacts_list_item, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        // inflate the GridView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);

        // initialize the view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        viewHolder.ivStarIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FavoriteStarImageView);
        viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // recycle the already inflated view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // update the item view
    ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
    if(item.icon != null)
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.icon));
    else
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stub);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
    viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);
    if(item.favoriteIcon)
    viewHolder.ivStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
    else
    viewHolder.ivStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important);
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    ImageView ivStarIcon;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvDescription;
}
```

}

```
class ListViewItem {
    public final String id;
    public final String icon;       // the drawable for the ListView item ImageView
    public final String title;        // the text for the ListView item title
    public final String description;  // the text for the ListView item description
    public final Boolean favoriteIcon;

    public ListViewItem(String id,String icon, String title, String description, Boolean favoriteIcon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.favoriteIcon = favoriteIcon;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewItem> implements View.OnClickListener
{

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.contacts_list_item, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        // inflate the GridView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);

        // initialize the view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        viewHolder.ivStarIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FavoriteStarImageView);
        viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // recycle the already inflated view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // update the item view
    ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
    if(item.icon != null)
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.icon));
    else
    viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stub);
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
    viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);
    if(item.favoriteIcon)
    viewHolder.ivStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
    else
    viewHolder.ivStarIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important);

    // sets onclick listener for the icon button
    viewHolder.ivStarIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  // TODO add to favorite list fragment
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    ImageView ivStarIcon;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvDescription;
}
```

you can then find a way to get the instance of the other fragment, and make changes to it in the onclick method. dont forget to call the notifydatachange after modifying list content

Comment: pass the instance of the other fragment(fragment2) to your custom adapter, then you create a method in the fragment2 class that's probably called "UpdateFavoriteList". call that method in your onclick method like getFragment2().UpdateFavoriteList();

Answer (score 0):

There exits an array containing all the data (ListViewItem in your sample code), so just put new items into this array and notify the adapter data set has been changed by calling

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: the list array of the favorite is different from the list array of the contacts, sorry i dont understand you..

Answer (score 0):

create a callback to update another fragment from the current fragment.

```
interface updatecallback 
{
  public void updatelist(User user);  //user is the parameter clicked in contacts fragment
}
```

implement the above interface in the parent activity of the contact fragment.

```
class parentActivity extends Activity implements updatecallback {


    //instantiating both fragments with the updatecallback instance
    Fragment f=new FavouritesFragment(favourite_list,this);
    Fragment f=new FavouritesFragment(contact_list,this);
    // other code
    public void updatelist(User user) {
        // update the favourites activity by adding the user to the userlist
        Fragment f=new FavouritesFragment(updated_user_list,this);
    }
```

the contactfragment

```
 public class ContactFragment extends Fragment 
    {
        private ,updatecallback updatecall;
        public ContactFragment(list,updatecallback updatecall)
        {
            this.updatecall=updatecall;
        }

        //while pressing star for a particular contact call in getview 
       ContactAdapter adapter=new ContactAdapter(list,updatecallback updatecall);

        }
    }
```

in contactadapter

```
  public class ContactAdapter  extends BaseAdapter
        {
            private ,updatecallback updatecall;
            public ContactAdapter  (list,updatecallback updatecall)
            {
                this.updatecall=updatecall;
            }

            //while pressing star for a particular contact call in getview 
            updatecall.updatecallback(list.get(position));
            }
        }
```

the idea is to populate the event to another fragment using callback

Comment: how can i do that?! from my adapter?!